Trouble listing databricks file names
I'm trying to access a notebook directory in databricks to list the notebooks found there on the console, but I am having issues with an SSL error.  I've found solutions online to do with changing my databrick configuration but it doesn't appear that I am able to manipulate this.
import requests
import json
from ast import literal_eval

# Authorization
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'token',
}

# Define rec_req as a function.
# Note: Default path is "/" which scans all users and folders.

def rec_req(instanceName,loc="/"):
 data_path = '{{"path": "{0}"}}'.format(loc)
 instance = instanceName
 url = '{}/api/2.0/workspace/list'.format(instance)
 response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=data_path)
 # Raise exception if a directory or URL does not exist.
 response.raise_for_status()
 jsonResponse = response.json()
 for i,result in jsonResponse.items():
   for value in result:
    dump = json.dumps(value)
    data = literal_eval(dump)
    if data['object_type'] == 'DIRECTORY':
     # Iterate through all folders.
     rec_req(instanceName,data['path'])
    elif data['object_type'] == 'NOTEBOOK':
     # Return the notebook path.
     print(data)
    else:
     # Skip imported libraries.
     pass
rec_req('instance_name')

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='instance_name', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/workspace/list (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)')))

Is there a solution to this issue or even a different way to access this information from within a databricks notebook?
Thank.
